# How to set up CloudFoudry in my data center

Tags: networking, cloud-foundry

I want to deploy a CloudFoundry private in my data center. I do want to expose port 80 traffic for internet accress.

I do not want to expose all the CloudFoundry roles (Cloud Controller, DEA, Haelth Manager. ..etc) on the public network.

Is a there a best practice document on configuring Cloud Foundry?

Do I need to implement a external router that will do port 80 port forwarding to Uhuru NGIX Router?

Comment: A good google group candidate for this question would be, https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/vcap-dev

Answer (score 1):

The network isolation is done at the cloud layer, i.e. vSphere, OpenStack, VCloud or AWS. Assuming you deploy this using bosh, you need to configure your networks so that everything is on a private network, except for the routers, which need to have an interface on the internet facing side. But in front of the routers, you should have your load balancers, so not even the routers need to be connected directly to the Internet.